# Different query execution plans being selected after SQL Server 2016 upgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have upgraded our database engines from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016 and since this has happened a number of queries in our stored procedures have been getting hung. After some investigation I found that the query execution plans had changed slightly. With the different execution plans some of our queries get hung and never seem to finish.

There doesn't seem to be a set pattern in what types of queries this is happening to but a specific issues is with a stored procedure with a looping merged with an example below. Similar logic exists throughout our environment and other similar queries are having issues as well. Would we be better off altering the code to force a better query execution plan or is there anything different with the configuration of SQL Server 2016 that would cause these different execution plans to be selected?

```
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE 
              @stillgoing BIT = 1
            , @rc_this INT = 0
            , @rc_ttl INT = 0

            WHILE @stillgoing = 1
            BEGIN

                WITH 
                ia AS 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        Field1,
                        Field2,
                        Field3,
                    , COALESCE(dw_updated_date, dw_created_date) AS LastModifiedDate
                    FROM SourceTable AS 
                )

                MERGE TOP(10000) INTO DestinationTable AS Target
                USING ia AS Source
                    ON (
                                Target.Field1 = Source.Field1       
                            )
                WHEN MATCHED
                    AND (
                           NULLIF(Source.Field1, Target.Field1) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Target.Field1, Source.Field1) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Source.Field2, Target.Field2) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Target.Field2, Source.Field2) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Source.Field3, Target.Field3) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Target.Field3, Source.Field3) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Source.[LastModifiedDate], Target.[LastModifiedDate]) IS NOT NULL
                        OR NULLIF(Target.[LastModifiedDate], Source.[LastModifiedDate]) IS NOT NULL
                        )
                    THEN
                        UPDATE
                        SET 
                              Field1 = Source.Field1
                            , Field2 = Source.Field2
                            , Field3 = Source.Field3
                            , [LastModifiedDate] = Source.[LastModifiedDate]
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
                    THEN
                        INSERT (
                              Field1
                            , Field2
                            , Field3
                            , [LastModifiedDate]
                            )
                        VALUES (
                              Source.Field1
                            , Source.Field2
                            , Source.Field3
                            , Source.[LastModifiedDate]
                            );
                    SET @rc_this = @@ROWCOUNT
                    SET @rc_ttl = @rc_ttl + @rc_this
                    IF @rc_this = 0 
                    SET @stillgoing = 0
            END 

            SELECT @rc_ttl AS ttl_mrgd;
```

Comment: what is the compatibility level?

Comment: Did you update statistics after the upgrade? They will horribly out of whack after an upgrade.

Comment: Have you also updated your database to a newer compatibility level? In SQL Server 2014 a new cardinality estimator was introduced that behaves differently than its predecessor. This could be a reason for the behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: compatibility level is at 130 for SQl 2016 and we have a nightly job that updates statistics but we did look at the cardinality differences between 2016 and 2012, we switched to the cardinality to 2012 mode and I am going to try some testing now, we are thinking this may be our issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The issue was cardinality estimator, for now we are setting the LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION to 1 until we can identify all queries that cause issues with the new CE and make needed changes.  Thanks @saso for the suggestion